# Graphically display perishable goods

Tags: anylogic

I am currently simulating on AnyLogic and I want to graphically visualize (change color) if a product stayed more in the shelf before it was actually bought.

I am using 3D objects, and how I am trying to simulate this is by having 2 parameters for each product, `CurrentDate` and `OverdueDate`. I am having problems writing the conditional for the transitions that triggers the color change, but I keep having an error also when I try changing the color with `SetColor`.

Comment: You need to be more specific on the error, we cannot help you with just "I get an error" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Changing 3D object color is not as easy as changing other things.

However, you could simply have 2 identical 3D objects that only vary in color. Then, change their visibility programmatically as below:

[image]